# ¿Como agregar un formatter a una bootstrap-table y Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

## ¿Como agregar un formatter a una bootstrap-table?

Saludos comunidad, tengo el siguiente inconveniente estoy utilizando la libreria bootstrap-table en un proyecto desarrollado con Angular 4, trato de agregar una funcion al data-formatter pero solo me muestra el nombre que pongo dentro del data-formatter="prueba" más no el return de la función, alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

```
<table id="table" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
         <th data-field="userId" data-sortable="true">Usuario</th>
         <th data-field="userName" data-sortable="true">Nombre</th>
         <th data-field="lastName" data-sortable="true">Apellido</th>
         <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Correo</th>
         <th data-field="mobilePhone">Teléfono</th>
         <th data-field="cargo">Cargo</th>
         <th data-field="evento" data-formatter="prueba">Eventos</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

En mi typescript:

```
tableRow(data){
    $(function () {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: data,
            pagination: true,
            pageNumber: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            search: true,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            iconsPrefix : 'icon',
            icons: {
              refresh: 'ion-ios-loop-strong',
              toggle: 'ion-ios-list-outline',
              columns: 'ion-ios-more'
            }
        });
        function prueba(){
          alert("oksd");
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es acceder al DOM de tu componente-hijo, que vendría siendo tu table, para esto utiliza el decorador `@ViewChild()` que te provee angular.

Seria algo como:

**HTML**

```
<table #tb data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true">

    ...

</table>
```

Y luego en tu archivo .ts lo declaras como una variable

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('tb') miTabla;

export class SarazaComponent imports OnInit {

   ngOnInit() { 
     console.log(this.miTabla);
   }

}
```

> De esta manera podes acceder a las propiedades, eventos y métodos de
>   tu componente.